# animation bug on quick mouseover mouseout

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to fix an animation bug when I quickly mouseover/mouseout an element?

This is the live version of the website - https://daphne-rebuild.netlify.app/

When I quickly hover on and off the circle, it becomes buggy. Happens all the time so I'm really hoping there's some kind of fix.

```html
<div class="hover-circle" @mouseover="hoverCircle" @mouseout="leaveCircle">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <span>Enter</span>
    </div>
```

```js
hoverCircle(e) {
      gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
        duration: 1,
        scale: 1.3,
        ease: "power4.out"
      });
      gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
        delay: 0.1,
        duration: 1,
        scale: 1.05,
        ease: "power4.out"
      });
    },
    leaveCircle() {
      gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
        duration: 0.5,
        scale: 1,
        ease: "power4.inOut"
      });
      gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
        duration: 0.5,
        scale: 1,
        ease: "power4.inOut"
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you placed a `delay` on `hoverCircle`. If `hoverCircle` and `leaveCircle` happen within less than `0.1s`, the delayed animation from `hoverCircle` will actually get executed after the animation from `leaveCircle`. Removing the `delay` will probably fix the problem.

I can't be sure from the code you posted, but you might also want to stop any currently playing animations on your element (both when entering and leaving). To do that, use...

```
gsap.killTweensOf(target)
```

..., documented [here](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.killTweensOf()).
In your example, it would probably look like:

```
hoverCircle() {
  gsap.killTweensOf(".hover-circle .circle");
  gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
    duration: 1,
    scale: 1.3,
    ease: "power4.out"
  });
  gsap.killTweensOf(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`);
  gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
    duration: 1,
    scale: 1.05,
    ease: "power4.out"
  });
},
leaveCircle() {
  gsap.killTweensOf(".hover-circle .circle");
  gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1,
    ease: "power4.inOut"
  });
  gsap.killTweensOf(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`);
  gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1,
    ease: "power4.inOut"
  });
}
```

If you have this in multiple places, you might want to refactor into a `method` called `stopAnimations`:

```
hoverCircle() {
  this.stopAnimations();
  gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
    duration: 1,
    scale: 1.3,
    ease: "power4.out"
  });
  gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
    duration: 1,
    scale: 1.05,
    ease: "power4.out"
  });
},
leaveCircle() {
  this.stopAnimations();
  gsap.to(".hover-circle .circle", {
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1,
    ease: "power4.inOut"
  });
  gsap.to(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`, {
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1,
    ease: "power4.inOut"
  });
},
stopAnimations() {
  gsap.killTweensOf(".hover-circle .circle");
  gsap.killTweensOf(`.home-${this.currentComponent}`);
}
```